# Async promise not returning result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

How come I do not get a value in my `res` after the promise resolves?

My console.log looks something like this:

```
=====!!USER NOT FOUND!!=====
Res: undefined
```

This is my function

```
async function findUser(userID, userType) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    usersTable.findOne (
        { _id: userID }
    ,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('findUser: ' + err);
        } else {
            if (!data) {
                console.log("=====!!USER NOT FOUND!!=====")
                resolve("NEW");
            } else {
                console.log("=====USER FOUND=====")
                resolve("OK");
            };
        };
    });
})};
```

This is my caller

```
async function main() {
    var res = "";
    try { 

        // Find the user
        res = await findUser(userEmail, "tenant");
        console.log("Res: " + res );
        if (res == "NEW") {
            res = await newUser();                  // Add the new tenant
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        console.log(" newBooking: " + err);
        callback( { error:true, err } );
    }
}
main();
```

Comment: You should reject instead of throwing an error

Comment: @Jonasw yes I saw that, I only throw err during development, once it works I reject instead. The `catch(err)` gets the `reject("error msg")` but I cannot understand why resolve does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find User should return sth:

```
async function findUser(userID, userType) {
   return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   ...
   });
}
```

If you do *await findUser()* youre waiting until the async function returns sth. Your async function returns undefined.

---

By the way: You might not use an async function at all:

```
function findUser(userId,userType){
  return new Promise(...);
}
```

Comment: Gaaaah!! How did I not see that!! hehehe of cause that was it.  Once again thank you so much Jonas :-)

Comment: Hmmmm...  ok let me update the question so you can see why I think I need the await....

Comment: ok Jonas - look at the caller. I need to do a lot of lookups (omitted from example) and add a new user, but only if the user does not exist. Do I not need to put await in the findUser function to do that?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard if everything happens inside the promise no.

Comment: I removed all unnecessary awaits and asyncs - everything still works :)